# Kafka Schema Registry for Protobuff

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, confluent-schema-registry

How does the schema used by the producer while sending the message land in kafka schema registry, as the producer will only know the generated class of the protobuff message.

Also, how does the cousumer use the schema registry, what role will the schema play while consumption apart from detecting incompatibility.

As per my understanding the consumer will already be receiving messages in the object of the class created by protobuff code generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated class has a method for getting its proto definition (`Message#getDescriptorForType()`). When the message is serialized, this method gets called and a schema is sent as text over HTTP to the registry, and returned with an ID. This ID is stored in the Kafka record; the actual schema is not.

When the consumer receives the byte-array from Kafka, it finds the ID, does an  HTTP GET request to the registry, then downloads the schema and uses this to deserialize the remainder of the message.

The [source code is available](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/tree/6.2.1-post/protobuf-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/protobuf) for you to understand this better.